# How to customize the color scatterplot legend handle

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend, scatter-plot

I have a seaborn scatterplot with datapoints distinguished by (1) color and (2) marker. This is the minimal code that generates the plot:

```
d = {'x': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'y': [2,4,6,8], 'Set': ["Set 1", "Set 1 ", "Set 2", "Set 2"], "Test_Type": ["Direct", "Natural","Direct", "Natural"]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="x", y="y", hue="Set", style="Test_Type")

plt.axis(ymin=0)
plt.xlabel("x values")
plt.ylabel("y values")
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

The "Set" legend markers are circles (colored according to the "Set" column in the dataframe), but I would like them to be something different, say a square. Of course I want the "Test_Type" markers to still be what they are: crosses, circles, whatever. I don't want that to change.

What I get vs What I'd like to get:

[image: What I get vs What I'd like to get]

I checked both the [seaborn scatterplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) and the [matplotlib markers](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html) documentation, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the legend manually, here each line in the legend it a custom item so we need to change items `[1, 2, 3]`:

```
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="x", y="y", hue="Set", style="Test_Type")

# get current legend's handles and labels
handles, labels =  ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

# modify items 1, 2, 3
change = [1, 2, 3]
for i in change:
    handles[i] = plt.Line2D([], [], color=handles[i].get_facecolor(),
                            marker='s', linestyle='')
# update the legend
ax.legend(handles, labels)
```

You can also identify the wanted labels automatically from the names in your column:

```
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="x", y="y", hue="Set", style="Test_Type")

handles, labels =  ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

# get unique labels
keep = set(df['Set'])
# {'Set 1', 'Set 1 ', 'Set 2'}

for i, l in enumerate(labels):
    if l in keep:   # if the label is in the column change to square
        handles[i] = plt.Line2D([], [], color=handles[i].get_facecolor(),
                                marker='s', linestyle='')
ax.legend(handles, labels)
```

Output:

[image]